# How to debug Flask with PyDev?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, flask, pydev

If I want to run your Flask app with PyDev, and I set breakpoints the debugger does not stop.

Another symptom is that killing the process form eclipse won't stop the process. When I rerun the app the port is already in use, because another instance is running.

This happens when

```
debug=True
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `debug=True` sets the `use_reloader=True` unless you set it explicitly to false. The solution is to set use_reloader to false:

```
use_reloader=False
```

But I wonder if there is a way to keep the reload going....

Comment: It may be worth looking at Flask and Werkzeug on Github to implement this. This is going to require internal knowledge, luckily it's well so shouldn't be to hard. Werkzeug is really easy to get to grips with and makes so much more sense with Flask than say Paste goes with other frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was enough:

- start remote debug server (Menu -> PyDev -> "Start Debug Server" -> Console = "Debug Server at port:5678"
- install pydevd (pip3 install pydevd)
- add init part to python code You want to debug:

  import pydevd
  pydevd.settrace()
- set some breakpoint on eclipse and run flask app (flask run)